# TextBox always focused

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a window with a TextBox and a Button. I want to always focus my TextBox, but allow the user to click the button. How can I do it?

I tried it by using a LostFocusEvent, that whould check who has the focus, and if it wasn't the Button it would focus the TextBox back, but I always get a System.StackOverflowException...

This what I was using:

```
    private void TextLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      IInputElement focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);

      if (focusedControl != btn && focusedControl != txt)
      {
        txt.Focus();
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Focus to the TextBox when it is lost. You can do this by first adding an EventHandler to the LostFocus event on the TextBox:

```
this.textBox.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(textBox_LostFocus);
```

This will then fire textBox_LostFocus every time the textbox loses focus. There you can set focus back to the TextBox again.

```
private void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ((TextBox)sender).Focus();
}
```

This will also allow buttons to still be pressed/used, and I have tested it with a table where you can select a row that doesn't become un-selected when the TextBox gains focus again.

Comment: When posting a code sample, please explain why this will help the author with their original problem.

Comment: This answer is the only one here that actually works to RESTORE focus to the textbox when it is lost. I will edit the answer to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

in the button click event you can give focus back to your text box like this.

```
textbox.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Textbox.Select();
```

Focus is a lower level method used for custom controls. I would stick to select() or activate()

Answer (score 0):

you could use ActiveControl Property to set focus to your text box.

```
    this.ActiveControl = yourTextboxName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to keep the focus on the `Textbox` even when clicking the `Button`.
To do that you have to make it so that the Button never gets focused in the first place instead trying to reverse something that already happend.

Here's a small example: `<Button Focusable="False"/>`

This way the focus will not be lost from the `Textbox`. and you are free to click the button.